# Unification Weirdness in Typeclass Instance

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, typeclass, unification, type-theory

Let's say I have the following (silly) class:

```
class BlindMap m where
    mapB :: m a -> m b
```

I could provide the following `[]` instance:

```
instance BlindMap [] where
    mapB = map id
```

The type of the RHS is `[a] -> [a]` which should unify with `[a] -> [b]`, but GHC doesn't think so:

```
Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘b’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for mapB :: [a] -> [b] at dingas.hs:11:5
  ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for mapB :: [a] -> [b] at dingas.hs:11:5
Expected type: a -> b
  Actual type: b -> b
Relevant bindings include
  mapB :: [a] -> [b]
In the first argument of ‘map’, namely ‘id’
In the expression: map id
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In short, `[a] -> [a]` and `[a] -> [b]` do indeed unify; but unification is not the operation of interest here. Instead, the operation of interest is type checking; "can this term be given this type?". `map id` cannot be given the type `[a] -> [b]` -- do you believe this, or is this also part of the confusion?

Comment: Yes, I hadn't realized that the types of method implementations must be _exactly_ equal to the type stipulated by the class, not just unifiable.

Comment: @TWhit Well, that's not quite accurate, either; for example, it's okay to give a method definition whose inferred type would be more general than the type demanded by the instance. (There are other exceptions as well.) But yes, that's the basic idea.

Comment: Would it be accurate to say that the method definition's inferred type may not be further concretized w.r.t. the class' stipulated type?

Comment: @TWhit I think talking about the definition's inferred type is misleading. Instead, the right thing to say is that the definition can be given the type specified by the class. It's totally possible to give a method definition whose type *cannot* be inferred (and does not even have a most general type), but which is accepted by the compiler -- so the real criteria is about type checking, not type inference.

Comment: By the way, I fully recognize that I'm using jargon that could easily hold a lot of meaning for me and little for you -- but it's tricky for me to spot which bits might be hard to understand. So please keep asking questions and talking about where you're most confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I missing here?

`map id` produces a list of values of some arbitrary type given a list of such values. `[a] -> [b]` promises to produce a list of values of some arbitrary type given a list of values of *potentially different* type.

Hence what it expects is `a -> b`, but your id-based function can only take what it returns, so `b -> b`.

Comment: _Potentially_ different, not _necessarily_ different. The specific type of `mapB` in the instance declaration is `[a] -> [a]`. Letting `m ~ []` since that's the body of the instance we're in, `[a] -> [a]` is unifiable with `[a] -> [b]` by letting `a ~ b`. Other examples include `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` ; `map id :: [a] -> [a]`, and in GHCi `:t [undefined :: a -> b, undefined a -> a]` yields `[undefined :: a -> b, undefined a -> a] :: [b -> b]`.

Comment: @TWhit you're confusing the two examples. In your case, the `id` function makes the type of the mapping more concrete, but that's because we're *outside* of the function and we're utilizing *one of its possible concretizations*. The inside of it still has to be implemented in a way that permits `a` and `b` to differ. What you're doing is implementing your function, not using it, hence what you wrote above isn't correct, since someone might want to use your class in a context where `a ~/~ b`.

Comment: Ok, I see; in a class instance I'm not permitted to concretize the type stipulated in the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, you said that you would provide functions with type:

```
forall a b.[a] -> [b]
```

in your instance definitions. The compiler took your word on that.

Now that you came up with an instance, the compiler really needs to see that miraculous function. And it rejects all code that does less than what you promised.

Before you continue, you should try to write a function

```
forall a b. a -> b
```

and you will see that you can at best come up with something like:

```
f x = f x
g x = error "not terminating."
```

And as long as there is no usable element mapping function, only the following instances can be written:

```
instance BlindMap (Maybe a) where mapB _ = Nothing
instance BlindMap ([a])     where mapB _ = []
```

and so on in the same spirit.